# SpecFlow Addin in SharpDevelop

Tags: .net, bdd, sharpdevelop, specflow

Is it possible to integrate SpecFlow into SharpDevelop as an addin?
Because i found this:
https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues#issue/18
but i can't make it work

Comment: I'd like to know if this is possible too.  Last time I tried I couldn't get it to work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is already implemented and will be included in the next SpecFlow release. You can use the latest [nightly build](http://build.specflow.org) to test it in the meanwhile.